# Find the PMF of $Y = (-1)^X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be Poisson Random Variable with parameter $\lambda$

- Find the PMF of $Y = (-1)^X$

My try :

$$P(Y= k) = P((-1)^X=k)$$ $k$ can only take on the values $1$ and $-1$

so $P (Y=1) = P(X \;\;\textbf{is even})$ and $P (Y=-1) = P(X \;\;\textbf{is odd})$ and here I'm stuck and I need help.

thank you .

Comment: Well, $[X\ \text{is even}]=[X=0]\cup[X=2]\cup[X=4]\cup\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $\mathsf P( Y=1) = e^{-\lambda}\cdot \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and the last factor of which is a somewhat well known Taylor series.